# Julia will not run on Windows 11

Tags: windows, installation, download, julia

I downloaded and installed Julia (ver. 1.9.3) on Windows 11. Upon installing, Julia fails to start succesfully through the desktop icon.

I tried clicking the desktop icon, as well as searching for it with the Windows searchbar and run it from there. Neither worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked by first running Julia from the cmd prompt. After that, Julia launches successfully via the typical Windows Icons. (I made this question in case anyone else struggles with this silly issue)